# Django ORM: Override related_name of Field in Child Class

Tags: django, django-models

I get this exception:

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError:
>
> Local field 'ticket' in class 'SpecialPlugin' clashes with field of similar name from base class 'BasePlugin'

Here are my models:

```
class BasePlugin(models.Model):
    ticket = models.OneToOneField('foobar.ticket', primary_key=True, 
                                  related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s')

    class Meta(IndexImplementation.Meta):
        abstract = True

    # .. Other stuff which should be available for SpecialPlugin 
    #    and other child classes.

class SpecialPlugin(BasePlugin):
    ticket = models.OneToOneField('foobar.ticket', primary_key=True, 
                                  related_name='special')
```

I only [found this note](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#field-name-hiding-is-not-permitted), but in my case the parent class is abstract. I am unsure if it applies here.

I want to give the child class `SpecialPlugin` the related name "special" since the related name (`%(app_label)s_%(class)s`) of the BasePlugin would break old code.

Is there a way to give SpecialPlugin.ticket the related_name "special"?

Comment: This error should only arise if the parent class is **not** abstract. I've just tested with simple models analogous to yours, and it works fine. If you look in the Django code that raises the exception, it checks whether the parent class is abstract or not. This suggests to me that `BasePlugin` isn't correctly being set as abstract. What is in `IndexImplementation.Meta`?

Comment: @solarissmoke IndexImplementation.Meta is abstract = True. That's why I don't understand the error message.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Update:

Similar thing can be done using django's [`default_related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#default-related-name) meta option.

---

It might look like an ugly hack, but you can set a function call to the `related_name` argument instead of string. And then override that function in the child class/model.

```
class BasePlugin(models.Model):

    @staticmethod
    def get_ticket_related_name():
        return '%(app_label)s_%(class)s'

    ticket = models.OneToOneField('foobar.ticket', primary_key=True, 
                                  related_name=get_ticket_related_name.__func__())

    class Meta(IndexImplementation.Meta):
        abstract = True


class SpecialPlugin(BasePlugin):
    @staticmethod
    def get_ticket_related_name():
        return 'special'
```

Comment: The get_ticket_related_name in my subclasses is never called.

Comment: @kzh Did you make sure: 1. Your base class is abstract. 2. Changing sequence of appearance/declaration on `get_ticket_related_name` method in subclass fixes it?

Comment: I'll try to arrange sequence. Thanks.

Comment: @v1k45 I just tried this solution, but it doesn't seem to be taking. The subclass defines the static method 'get_ticket_related_name'.  But the baseclass's method is the one being called.  (And the baseclass is abstract)

The only difference I can see is the Meta of the Base is using IndexImplementation, where mine is not.  But I can't seem to find what that class is?

Comment: @albrnick I'm not sure about this, but I have discovered that something similar already exists in django. Lookup `default_related_name` meta option. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#default-related-name

Comment: Oh perfect!  That worked great, Thanks! = )  (I'm guessing the issue with the staticmethod was that the OneToOneField was getting created at the time of BasePlugin and not SpecialPlugin.  So it was resolving to the BasePlugin's get_ticket_related_name. (Esp since it isn't a true abstract class, just a flag set)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the core of the problem is in the overriding of model field [Django model inheritance, overriding fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19025586/django-model-inheritance-overriding-fields)

Simple workaround for you problem will be to decouple BasePlugin to to class without `ticket` field and then create a child class that contains `ticket` field

```
class BaseWithoutTicketPlugin(models.Model):
    # .. Other stuff which should be available for SpecialPlugin 
    #    and other child classes.
    class Meta(IndexImplementation.Meta):
        abstract = True

class BasePlugin(BaseWithoutTicketPlugin):
    ticket = models.OneToOneField('foobar.ticket', primary_key=True, 
                                  related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s')

    class Meta(BaseWithoutTicketPlugin.Meta):
        abstract = True


class SpecialPlugin(BaseWithoutTicketPlugin):
    ticket = models.OneToOneField('foobar.ticket', primary_key=True, 
                                  related_name='special')
```

Idea is to use `BaseWithoutTicketPlugin` when you need to customize `ticket` and use `BasePlugin` when you don't.

Comment: BasePlugin has other attributes which are needed. I need to inherit from it. Sorry, I was stripping down my code for the question ... maybe to much was stripped. I update the question.

Comment: @guettli Still don't see problem in my suggestion, I updated my answer.

Comment: the "Other stuff" part needs the attribute "ticket". This means you need to move this part to "BasePlugin". After doing this, the other-stuff-part is no more available for SpecialPlugin :-(

Answer (score 1):

Using default related name in Meta class:

```
class SpecialPlugin(BasePlugin):
    class Meta:
        default_related_name = 'special_plugins'
```