# Python programmatically define variables in class body

Tags: python, django

I have two django models, model `Person` and model `PersonTemplate` that have the exact same field names & types, with the exception being that some of the fields are required in `Person`, whereas they are not in `PersonTemplate`. It's easy enough to just copy paste the models into both of these classes, but that involves a lot of hard-coding and if I edit one model and forget the other, stuff might break.

The solution I have in mind is to define the django model fields in a function that takes a boolean argument, whether or not the fields are required. Something like

```
def get_fields(is_required=True):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name=_("First Name"),
                                  blank=is_required, null=is_required)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name=_("Last Name"),
                                 blank=is_required, null=is_required)
    return locals()

class Person(models.Model):    
    vars = get_fields(True)

class PersonTemplate(models.Model):    
    vars = get_fields(False)
```

What I don't know how to do is get the local variables from `get_fields` into the class body of the models. Anybody have any ideas, or suggestions for a better way to implement these models?

Answer (score 1):

Django has Abstract models which you can use do define repetitive fields and methods and then inherit then to an actual model of your choice.

And for dynamic required field, you can set their values using model methods and override those methods in child model. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43093779/4726598).

Something like this should work:

```
class AbstractPerson(models.Model):
    @staticmethod
    def get_first_name_requirement():
        return True

    @staticmethod
    def get_last_name_requirement():
        return True


    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name=_("First Name"),
                                  blank=get_first_name_required.__func__(), null=get_first_name_required.__func__())
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name=_("Last Name"),
                                 blank=get_last_name_required.__func__(), null=get_last_name_required.__func__())
    class Meta(object):
        abstract = True

class Person(AbstractPerson):    
    @staticmethod
    def get_first_name_requirement():
        return True

    @staticmethod
    def get_last_name_requirement():
        return True


class PersonTemplate(AbstractPerson):    
    @staticmethod
    def get_first_name_requirement():
        return False

    @staticmethod
    def get_last_name_requirement():
        return False
```

I am sure there must be more elegant way for dynamically assigning null values. But this too will get the job done.

Comment: Thought this was what OP was asking at first too, but they're asking how to avoid repetition while changing the field definitions attributes for `is_required` dynamically.

Comment: Oh, my bad, i didn't read the question properly, will update my answer.

Comment: @v1k45 this doesn't work for me. I put print statements in the abstract `get_first_name_requirement` and the `PersonTemplate`'s `get_first_name_requirement` and only the abstract function is fired, which means that the model attributes are not being redefined. I think a solution here that would work is using `locals()` to set the model fields programatically.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve you idea you need to use metaclasses. But as usual this is bad idea.
Why do not you look at Django Abstract models and inheritance? This will solve your question in much more readable and simple way.