# Override Field attribute in Django Model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a problem. I'm trying to change the directory on which a file gets uploaded, using the upload_to attribute of a FileField, without success.

The main issue is that I have defined a parent class, with a file attribute, and I want to change the directory on the child class.

My models are defined in this way :

```
class DocumentBase(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_filename)


class Document(DocumentBase):
    file_type = models.CharField(max_size=150)
```

I tried to overwrite the FileField in the child class, without success (I'm aware now that this is not possible.)

I also tried the answers on this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42899817/django-orm-override-related-name-of-field-in-child-class) (that is very similar to my problem), without success.

Could somebody help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As Willem said this can be solved monkey patching the `upload_to` attribute. But it didn't work for this case.

Digging into the [FileField class definition](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/db/models/fields/files/#FileField), this class has another attribute: `generate_filename`. This attribute is filled when `upload_to` is callable.
This attribute is used to generate the file filename.

So, the solution that worked was :

```
class DocumentBase(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_filename)


class Document(DocumentBase):
    file_type = models.CharField(max_size=150)

Document._meta.get_field('file').generate_filename = other_get_filename
```

This behavior changes on Django 1.10.

Comment: What Django version were you using?